# queue of structs in C language

Tags: c, struct, queue

I am trying to create a simple program in C language using queues and structs .... to be a ticketing system.

ticket includes:

1. ticket id (to search with)
2. name
3. age
4. favorite movie

options to choose from:

1. add new ticket (enqueue)
2. search and display one ticket
3. Delete all  (empty queue)
4. Display all tickets

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
void enQueue(int);
void deQueue();
void display();
void search();
struct ticket_details
{
    int ticket_id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char movie[50];

};

struct ticket_details ticket_details;
int items[SIZE];
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
int ticket_number=0;
int search_number=0;
void main() {
  int choice = 0;
printf("1-buy ticket\n2-search for a ticket\n3-display all tickets\n4-delete a ticket\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
   switch(choice) {
      case '1' :
      ticket_number++;
      enQueue(ticket_number);
         break;
      case '2' :
        printf("ticket number:");
        scanf("%d",&search_number);
        search(search_number);
      case '3' :
         printf("display all tickets\n");
         display();
         break;
      case '4' :
         printf("ticket number:\n");
         scanf("%d",&ticket_number);
         deQueue(ticket_number);
         break;
      default :
         printf("Invalid choice\n" );
   }

}
void enQueue(int value) {
  if (rear == SIZE - 1)
    printf("\nNo more tickets!!");
  else {
    if (front == -1)
      front = 0;
    rear++;
    items[rear] = value;
      printf("Name:");
      scanf("%s",ticket_details[value].name);
      printf("age:");
      scanf("%d",&ticket_details[items[rear]].age);
      printf("Movie:");
      scanf("%s",ticket_details[items[rear]].movie);
  }
}
void deQueue(int value) {
  if (front == -1)
    printf("\nNo tickets to delete");
  else {
    int i;
    for (i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    if(i==value)
    free(value);

    printf("\nDeleted : %d", ticket_details[front]);

  }
}
// Function to print the queue
void display() {
  if (rear == -1)
    printf("\nNo tickets found");
  else {
    int i;
    printf("\nAll tickets:\n");
    for (i = front; i <= rear; i++)
      printf("%d/n", &ticket_details[i].ticket_id+
            "%s/n",ticket_details[i].name+
            "%d/n",ticket_details[i].age+
            "%s/n",ticket_details[i].movie);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
void search(int search_number) {
    int i;
    for (i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    if(i==search_number)
      printf("%d/n", &ticket_details[search_number].ticket_id+
            "%s/n",ticket_details[search_number].name+
            "%d"/n,ticket_details[search_number].age+
            "%s"/n,ticket_details[search_number].movie);
            else
            {
                printf("Ticket number not found");
            }
}
```

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to actually include a question. What is the problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Wrong output?

Comment: the code is not working ... i don't know how to do it if you can help me with my code or if you a have a code that do the same function to compare.

Comment: Hint: `scanf("%d",&choice);` reads an *integer* value into `choice`, but your `switch` uses e.g. `case '1'` which is a *character*. There's no known character encoding where `1 == '1'`.

Comment: There's also a lot of other bad stuff in your code, which makes it seem like you haven't been paying attention in class or skipped some chapters in your text book. Take for example `free(value);` in the `deQueue` function. That won't work very well.